# IntelliJ Environment Variables

Tags: intellij-idea

Trying to understand why the environment variable is red here but, the other environment variables a normal white color. What does the red indicate?

[image]

Comment: How did you go to that window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color indicates that you've modified this environment variable (it's different from the system default).